# Variable value in graphql mutation isn't saving

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I have simple mutation with variables as:

**Mutation Query**

```
 mutation M($name: String) {
 Adduser(name: $name) {
  _id
  name
 }
}
```

**Query variables**

```
{
  "name":"user1"
}
```

And in *graphql API*:

```
app.post('/graphql', (req, res) => {
 const query = req.body.query;
 const  vars = req.body.variables;
 //console.log(vars);/*showing {  "name":"user1" }*/
   graphql(Schema, query, null, vars).then(result => {
     res.send(result);
   });
});
```

but the output i am getting is:

```
  {
 "data": {
   "Adduser": {
     "_id": "593a2cd4cf057a07d073e971",
     "name": null
    }
  }
}
```

***Updated***

**userType:**

```
const Adduser = {
type: userType,
args: {
    name: {
        type: graphql.GraphQLString
    },
    age: {
        type: graphql.GraphQLInt
    }
},
resolve: (obj, args) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var user=new User({
            name:args.name
            });
        user.save(function(err,usr){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            else{
                resolve(usr);
            }
        }); 
    })
}
};
```

**mutation:**

```
const Rootmutation = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'Rootmutation',
fields: {
    Adduser: Adduser
}
});

 const schema = new graphql.GraphQLSchema({
query: Rootquery,
mutation: Rootmutation
});
```

It means the variable value is not binding with mutation query.

Any suggestion here??

Comment: The problem comes from within your mutation and/or your User `name` resolve function. Can you show us your mutation code and your User resolvers ?

Comment: please see updated question

Comment: Please add User class and UserType